# Best Practices for embedding .NET assemblies in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, assemblies

What are some important practices to follow when creating a .NET assembly that is going to be embedded to SQL Server 2005?

I am brand new to this, and I've found that there are significant method attributes like:

```
[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow", TableDefinition = "letter nchar(1)")]
```

I'm also looking for common pitfalls to avoid, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some that I remember:

- Keep its usage to a minimum, only use it when T-SQL proved too complex.
- Avoid pointers/cursors at all costs because a for loop is so easily abusable in CLR context.
- Only use the SQL-Server native data types unless totally necessary.

Can't remember where I've found the information, but those are some that I do remember.

Basically, only use it when declarative T-SQL is too complex or is impossible to do (such as registry editing etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Single tip regarding assembly deployment:

Keep functionality isolated across small assemblies. Try not to build a dependency chain, because replacing a base assembly means you need to remove the dependent assemblies *first*, before you can update the base assembly.

Answer (score -1):

I would strongly advise against putting .net assemblies in your database server, think n-tier applications. Persistence <- Business Logic <-Presentation Logic <- client
Keep your Logic in your Business Logic layer.

The only reason I can think of to put .net in your database would to add a new complex data type, I would strongly that this be a dumb class that only holds data and does no processing on it.

Just because you can does not mean you should. 
Sorry for not directly answering your question.

Comment: Sometimes data access also requires more logic than is built in to SQL server, and deploying this on the database server doesn't make it less part of the logical DAL .

Comment: I use .NET assemblies for functional check constraints, so those using Management Studio can't accidentally type a badly formatted email address, for example, into a field.  It keeps the database data perfectly valid, no matter how it is edited, and the constraints are much easier to write and maintain in C#.  Since they're written in C#, the same code that constrains the data in the database also constrains the data in the application level, so its highly centralized and very easy to maintain.